# Javascript to return content/string which doesn't fit in given width and height of UIWebView

Tags: javascript, html, ios, objective-c, uiwebview

Assume i have some strings inside my div,

**"This is a dummy text inside my html.This is just a test"**.

And i will load it to UIWebView where my webview width=100,height=20.Now assume only **"This is a dummy text inside"**  fits in webview.

Now i want my javascript to return me the remaining strings **"my html.This is just a test"**(which doesn't fit because of less height).

Here i don't want to resize my webview,i just want the remaining strings which doesn't fit in my UIWebView.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated...

```
                                     ***I'm newbiew to javascript...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Below JS function.. it will return the Overflow text..

example :

```
load_content('foo','Sample Text',30,100);


<script type="text/javascript">
    function load_content(div_tag_id,content_string,height,width){

        var text_fit = "";
        var text_overflow = "";
        var string_array = content_string.split(" ");

        for(var i = 0; i < string_array.length; i++ ) {

            document.getElementById(div_tag_id).style.width = width+"px";
            document.getElementById(div_tag_id).innerHTML = document.getElementById(div_tag_id).innerHTML + " "+string_array[i];
            if(document.getElementById(div_tag_id).offsetHeight > height) {
                text_overflow += " "+string_array[i];
            } else {
                text_fit += " "+string_array[i];
            }
        }
        document.getElementById(div_tag_id).innerHTML = text_fit;
        return text_overflow;

    }   
</script>
```